# List's and while loops - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new to Python and I am stuck on a particular question and I thought i'd ask you guys.

The following contains my code so far, aswell as the questions that lie therein:

```
list=[100,20,30,40 etc...]
```

Just a list with different numeric values representing an objects weight in grams.

```
object=0

while len(list)>0:
   list_caluclation=list.pop(0)
   print(object number:",(object),"evaluates to")
```

What i want to do next is evaluate the items in the list. So that if we go with index[0], we have a list value of 100. THen i want to separate this into smaller pieces like, for a 100 gram object, one would split it into five 20 gram units. If the value being split up was 35, then it would be one 20 gram unit, on 10 gram unit and one 5 gram unit.

The five units i want to split into are: 20, 10, 5, 1 and 0.5.

If anyone has a quick tip regarding my issue, it would be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Don't call your own object `list`, it shadows the build-in. Also: what is your actual question?!

Comment: I think the OP first needs an algorithm of how to achieve number splitting

Comment: As you mentioned, a poorly formatted question. But @gefei is correct, an algorithm is what i need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should think about solving this for a single number first. So what you essentially want to do is split up a number into a partition of known components. This is also known as the [Change-making problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem). You can choose a greedy algorithm for this that always takes the largest component size as long as it’s still possible:

```
units = [20, 10, 5, 1, 0.5]
def change (number):
    counts = {}
    for unit in units:
        count, number = divmod(number, unit)
        counts[unit] = count
    return counts
```

So this will return a dictionary that maps from each unit to the count of that unit required to get to the target number.

You just need to call that function for each item in your original list.

Comment: Thank you both poke and @danielmcdonald, super helpful. I'll definitly use this website more often. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it with a double for loop.  The outer loop would be the *numbers* you input and the inner loop would be the *values* you want to evaluate (ie [20,10,5,1,0.5]). For each iteration of the inner loop, find how many times the *value* goes into the *number* (using the floor method), and then use the modulo operator to reassign the *number* to be the remainder.  On each loop you can have it print out the info that you want :) Im not sure exactly what kind of output you're looking for, but I hope this helps!

Ex:

```
import math
myList=[100,20,30,40,35]
values=[20,10,5,1,0.5]
for i in myList:
    print(str(i)+" evaluates to: ")
    for num in values:
        evaluation=math.floor(i/num)
        print("\t"+str(num)+"'s: "+str(evaluation))
        i%=num
```